# Getting a list of all guild members

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I'm trying to get all the user IDs in my discord server. I am able to pull in a Collection Map however I'm not familiar with them so I would really appreciate it if someone could explain how I'm suppose to get everyone's IDs using this collection map. I really appreciate your help thanks!

Here is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'HIDDEN';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    const list = bot.guilds.cache.get("HIDDEN"); 
    console.log(list.members);

})

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Guild.members.cache` to get a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) of members. You can then use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (which works on [Collections](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) too) to map the users by their ID.

Example:

```js
const Guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("GuildId")
const Members = Guild.members.cache.map(member => member.id);
console.log(Members)
// --> ['UserId', 'UserId', 'UserId', 'UserId', 'UserId','UserId' 'UserId' etc...]
```

Comment: 10/10 Thanks so much!